# Retry api call a couple of times from within redux epic using rxj

Tags: ajax, redux, rxjs, request, retry-logic

#### The issue is as follow:

In a **react** project that uses **redux** epics and **rxjs** inside epics for api calls i have to make a request to which the servers almost all the time returns error the first time, because of some server delay issues and if the page is being refreshed after (let say 5-10 or 15 sec) the error disappears.

So how can i make a retry request on error a couple of times with a delay of 5 sec in between so that if i get the data as response the page will get automatically updated without the need of refresh.

Make initial request --> if error try after 5 seconds --> if there is still an error try again after 5 seconds... and this should keep on repeating until a maximum number of calls defined at the beginning is reached (let say 5).

#### This is what i have tried and for some reason this piece of code is not working.

**1. The recursiveAjaxCall function**

Here i am trying to make api request recursively but for some reason the code enters this function just once which is on the first call.

```
const recursiveAjaxCall = (params, maxRetries, delayInterval, currentRetries) => {
  return ajax({
    ...params
  }).pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      if (currentRetries < maxRetries) {

        console.log(`Retry attempt count: ${currentRetries + 1}`);

        return of(error).pipe(
          delay(delayInterval),
          switchMap(() =>
            recursiveAjaxCall(params, maxRetries, delayInterval, currentRetries + 1, fromMsg)
          )
        );
      }
      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
};
```

**2.  The epic responsible for calling the above function**

```
const epicNameFn = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
  switchMap((action) => {
    const params = {
       url: someUrl,
       method: 'GET',
     };

     const maxRetries = 5;
     const delayInterval = 5 * 1000;
     const currentRetries = 0;

     return recursiveAjaxCall(params, maxRetries, delayInterval, currentRetries ).pipe(
       map(response => return sliceSuccess(response.response)),
       catchError(error => of(sliceFailuer(error)))
     );
  })
);
```